# Is this correct or do i need to add more : MySQL joining tables

Tags: mysql

so i wanted to join two tables and i wrote:vehicle and policy
  Select registrationNo, policyNumber, Make
  Where registrationNo.vehicle = Registration.No.policy

Is this correct?

Comment: why you don't test it out and see errors to guide you ?

Comment: @4givN please downvote and flag to close the question instead of only commenting

Comment: No- you are missing a from statement a join statement , table names should precede the column name and the where statement should be an on statement. Go read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

There are some type of joins, depending on your needs.

If you are using MySQL, find more information here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

A possible solution for you (without more information) could be:

SELECT * FROM vehicle LEFT JOIN policy ON vehicle.id=policy.id;